# Apache RewriteRule [L,R=301] does not redirect on some servers

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/primary/
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(wp-admin|wp-content)
RewriteRule primary/(.*) /$1 [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

The above is (part of) my HTACCESS configuration.  Specifically, the last 2 rules.  Basically, any URLs that aren't pointing to wp-admin/wp-content should be rewritten to remove a folder name (primary).

This works on my local Apache environment, but it does not perform the redirect on the target server.  It sends just sends me to the URL I requested and throws a 404 because the page does not exist.

```
Apache version: 2.2.3
URL: http://example.com/primary/decks-and-patios/
Expected result: http://example.com/decks-and-patios/
Actual result: http://example.com/primary/decks-and-patios/

Apache version: 2.2.29
URL: http://example.local/primary/decks-and-patios/
Expected result: http://example.local/decks-and-patios/
Actual result: http://example.local/decks-and-patios/
```

Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: Does a physical folder/file with the name `primary` exist on the second server? If so, you most likely just need to disable MultiViews option.

Comment: There is a folder called `primary`, I will try that.

Comment: UPDATE: Sorry, I was confused, the first domain (example.com) has a folder called `primary` but the local version (example.local) does not.  Would disabling MultiViews still fix this issue?